# How to Send Mail Asynchronously Using Django's Async View?

Tags: python, django

I am building a project, and I want to send a notifying e-mail when User takes a specific action.

I did some search and managed to achieve this using `threading.Thread`. Since Django now fully supports async view, I want to do it with async function.

Here is what I tried:

```
from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.shortcuts import render
from myproj.settings import EMAIL_HOST_USER
import asyncio

asend_mail = sync_to_async(send_mail)

async def index(request):
    asyncio.create_task(
        asend_mail(
            subject='Test',
            message='Lorem ipsum',
            from_email=EMAIL_HOST_USER,
            recipient_list=['ezon@stackoverflow.dummy']
        )
    )
    return render(request, 'myapp/index.html', {})
```

However, when I request this index page, I still get response AFTER `asend_mail` coroutine complete.

I have tried the following simple async function (from a tutorial), and everything works as expected.

```
async def async_print():
    for num in range(1, 6):
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print(num)

async def index(request):
    asyncio.create_task(async_print())
    return render(request, 'myapp/index.html', {})
```

I wander what is the key difference between the above two scenarios.

I am using python 3.10.7, django 4.1.2, daphne 3.0.2 (as the server, NOT django's development server).

I am new to async/await feature. I will be appreciate it if someone can give a comprehensive explanation.

Comment: You will have to add a wrapper that `await`s on `asend_mail`

Comment: Could you give some code snippet? I just tried `async def real_asend_mail(*args, **kwargs): await asend_mail(*args, **kwargs)`, and called `real_asend_mail`, but still got the respond after mail sent.

Comment: Oh yeah that looks good. Also to confirm you still used `asyncio.create_task(real_asend_mail(...))`? If it still doesn't work, can you try adding `thread_sensitive=False` to your `sync_to_async`?

Comment: Adding `thread_sensitive=False` did the job. Thank you! But why? Does it have anything to do with me running Daphne in the console, so that the server only have one process?

Answer (score -1):

I would have tried threading (see: https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/ for ref.)

I used it for uploading 1000's of (large) files on an S3 bucket. It was like 70x faster then doing it sequentially.

The idea is that this email task will be wrapped in a thread, and the thread will be issued, and your code will continue from there rather then waiting for the task (in the thread) to be completed.

Comment: I would like know answers regarding `async/await` functions. I know how to send email in sub-thread.